# Returns and/or breaks in the middle of a loop. Is it ever acceptable?

Tags: function, language-agnostic, loops, return, break

Suppose we have an array of integers. We've written a function to fetch the index of the first specified value in the array, or -1 if the array does not contain the value..

So for example, if the `array = { 4, 5, 4, 4, 7 }`, then `getFirstIndexOf(4)` would return 0, `getFirstIndexOf(7)` would return 4, and `getFirstIndexOf(8)` would return -1.

Below, I have presented three different ways to write this function. It is a widely accepted coding standard that `returns` in the middle of functions, and `breaks` in the middle of loops are poor practice. It seems to me that this might be an acceptable use for them.

```
public int getFirstIndexOf(int specifiedNumber) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == specifiedNumber) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

VS.

```
public int getFirstIndexOf(int specifiedNumber) {
  int result = -1;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == specifiedNumber) {
      result = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

VS.

```
public int getFirstIndexOf(int specifiedNumber) {
  int result = -1;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == specifiedNumber && result == -1) {
      result = i;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

What do you think? Which is best? Why? Is there perhaps another way to do this?

Comment: Where did you read that breaking out of a loop was poor practice?  There are plenty of reasons to exit a loop early.

Comment: @George, I've heard that `break` was in the same league as `continue` and `goto`. Also, the MISRA coding guidelines used to advise against using `break`.

Comment: And people who tell you not to use `break` are on the same level of idiocy as the people who tell you not to use `goto`...

Comment: For what it's worth, a good half of all real-world loops have a continuation condition that must be checked in the *middle* of the loop body, not at the start/end.

Comment: Breaking out of a loop as soon as you're done with your computation makes sense. Save cycles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why **do...while** & **while** loop was invented.

As requested:

```
public int getFirstIndexOf(int specifiedNumber) {
    int i = array.Length;
    while(--i > -1 && array[i] != specifiedNumber);

    return i;       
}
```

Comment: Ehhh, I don't think so. In general (I _think_ some languages vary), `do...while` and `while` still only check the loop condition at the start of each loop iteration. They're not a substitute for breaking out from the middle.

Comment: do...while loops check the condition at the end of the of the loop iteration, while loops check it at the top.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of `do-while` loops. Could you write up a version of `getFirstIndexOf` from the OP using a `do-while`?

Comment: Irrelevant semantics in this case. Except for the first or last iteration, the end of the loop iteration is the same as the start.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's poor practice to run a full loop when you have already found your result...

If you really want to avoid using return from the middle of the loop, I would sugest to use a "sentinel" to stop your loop.

```
public int getFirstIndexOf(int specifiedNumber, int[] array) {

    boolean found = false;
    boolean exit = false;
    int i = 0;
    int arraySize = array.length();

    while(!found && !exit) {
        if(array[i] == specifiedNumber) {
            found = true;
        } else {
            if(i++ > arraySize) {
            exit = true;
            }
        }

    if(found ==true) {
       return i;
    } else {
       return 99999;
    }
}
```

edit: I hate to indent code using spaces in StackOverflow...

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with sentinels. Could you rewrite the `getFirstIndexOf` method in the OP so everyone can see what you mean?